# Nuclear synthesis and neutron star collisions

Tags: neutron-stars, nucleosynthesis

When I look up the wikipedia article on nuclear synthesis, this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nucleosynthesis_periodic_table.svg picture tells me that quite a lot of chemical elements would have been created by "merging neutron stars".

This looks odd, as for the merging of neutron stars it takes at least two of them and I'm not aware that there really so many of them out there.

What's wrong here, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be estimating a probability for two isolated neutron stars to find each other in space and collide. Such interactions are indeed extremely rare; even in collisions between entire galaxies, the odds of two stars colliding with each other are slim. Space is big and mostly empty.

However, my understanding is that single stars (like our Sun) are relatively rare. Most star formation happens in open clusters, and multiple star systems --- binary stars, triple stars, and so on --- probably outnumber singletons. In a star-forming region, some systems will be high-mass binaries which evolve rapidly to a pair of neutron stars. A neutron star pair in a close orbit emits gravitational waves which extract energy from the orbit, and eventually the neutron stars will merge. We have [discovered several such pairs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulse%E2%80%93Taylor_binary), and gravitational-wave observatories have [observed some mergers](https://astronomy.com/news/2019/04/ligo-detects-gravitational-waves-from-another-neutron-star-merger).

Comment: Given the difficulty of detecting neutron stars, having seen many albeit, and, in pairs, is a very plausible explanation.